# How to Click (place Cursor Blinking) in a TextArea (textbox) using Javascript without using Mouse Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, textarea

I want to Click (place Cursor Blinking) in a `TextArea` (textbox) using `Javascript` without using Mouse Click. 
After clicking in the textarea the Javascript code should continue to more steps.
The code should work from `Console` of `Browser` like in Chrome => press F12 => select Console tab. 
**Note:** just `focus()`, `element.Value='abc'` or `select()` is not required. Please help. Thanks

Comment: i have tried document.getElementById('id').focus(), document.getElementById('id').select(), document.getElementById('id').value='abc'

Comment: Neither with any of the codes provide a Genuine-Mouse-Click in the text area with Blinking Cursor

Answer (score 2):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/f9y9vvb7/), you will get blinking cursor

```
$('textarea').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this (.focus() on DOM elements)

```
document.getElementById("txtField").focus();
```

**Update** If you are creating server controls. For example:asp.net server controls then you need to specify ClientIDMode="Static" on input control

Comment: sorry, but i require simple click on simple normal page just like Google Search page

Comment: element.value='abc' puts 'abc' in the TextField but Not the genuine-mouse-click, you can try that

Comment: is your control is client side control or server side control? server side control has runat="server"

Comment: client side control. Focus, select, value etc all work but i just want to make a Click inside the textbox (that places cursor in in), you can try that.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in Google's page, its working (on Console) just for adding text to the Search-Textbox, but not places cursor blinking in it.

> document.getElementById('lst-ib').value='abc'

sorry to Google, this is just to learn, i want solution for my own projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want textarea to be focused as soon as page is loaded, just do this:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textarea" autofocus></textarea>
```

add ***autofocus***

Comment: dear, autofocus can be used just when you are developing or editing a web-page, but i want to try on a working running webpage